# Given n, how to return an n-nested defaultdict?

Tags: python, nested, defaultdict

I want to write a function that will return a nested defaultdict, depending on the value of input n.

For n=1, it should return `defaultdict(int)`.

For n=3, it should return 
`defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))`.

My best attempt is this:

```
def get_nested_defaultdict(n: int):
    bottom_dict = defaultdict(int)
    nested_dict = defaultdict
    for i in range(n):
        nested_dict = nested_dict(lambda: bottom_dict)
    return nested_dict
```

But this fails on the 2nd iteration:

`TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def defaultdict_gen(n: int):
  if n < 1:
    raise ValueError()
  if n == 1:
    return defaultdict(int)
  return defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict_gen(n - 1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  d = defaultdict_gen(2)
  print(d)
  print(d[0][0])
```